# Media Gallery - Cannot upload images

Tags: magento2, image-upload, media, gallery, magento2.4.3.p1

i've created a brand new Magento 2.4.3-p1 installation and using the media gallery i'm getting some errors.
The main error is when i'm trying to upload images i always get the error below

[image]

One other issue is when i access one folder...sometimes not all the images are displayed.
For example, below are 2 prints, from FTP Folder and from media gallery
[image]
[image]

Can someone help me understand what is wrong at my end and how to fix this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
 $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('catalog/product/product_attachment');
        try {
            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(
                ['fileId' => 'product_attachment']
            );
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'png' , 'jpeg']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($target);
```

Comment: thanks...i've managed to fix this...it was a bug in a template that add a FrontEndBuilder that was causing the issue